# ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000]

Tags: texlive, glossaries, memory

I am writing a thesis, it is very long now over 300 pages. I am using glossary package a lot, and I am using two computers. When I compile my .tex file over my laptop I get the following error:

! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
\l__morewrites_internal_tl ...lsnumberformat}{257}

while when I compile it over my PC, It compiles without any issue. In both systems I am using TexLive and I also used morewrites package to deal with similar error I had before. Does anyone know why? Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This usually happens because of a loop that fills the memory; but it can also be a result of trying to do too much. You can try adding `\end{document}` at mid document and compile, so that only half of the document is processed. If it's successful, move `\end{document}` forward, otherwise backwards: you can so possibly isolate the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your fast comment, I identified the guilty Chapter that I have written, but why do you think it should work on my PC and not on my laptop? Don't you think there should be some memory configuration difference between them?

Comment: It can be. What TeX distribution are you using on the PC?

Comment: I installed last week TeXLive version 2013, on both my PC station and my laptop. My guess is that because compiling takes over 5 min, and the laptop is slower than my PC Station.

Comment: It is maybe interesting for you to hear that before I was working with MiKTeX 2.9, and I got error for it when the project was getting bigger, and by switching to TeXLive 2013 I could still continue my project.

Comment: I increased the memory to 6,000,000 from 5,000,000 in the texmf.cnf file and then ran fmtutil-sys --all, and every thing is fine after. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, that question is more complete. Do you close it? or I should?

Comment: I voted for closing. Don't worry about it and continue to contribute to the site! Welcome again!